# For Loops Java Unreachable Statement

Tags: java, unreachable-code

I keep getting an error thrown at the line that I have put a comment above the line that says "unreachable statement." How can I fix this? Is there anything else wrong with this code?

```
boolean containsAll(IntSet [] s) {


    return false;

    // Unreachable Code begins here
    for (int y = 0; y< s.length; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i< s[y].arr.length; i++) {
            if (s[y].contains(i)) {
                if (i>=arr.length) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!arr[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The `return false` statement ends the method there and nothing after is executed.

Comment: Why do you have this return false at the beginning of the method ? It must be a mistake. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

As @Eli suggested whenever you have return condition before some statements in a function it will never reach that code hence will give you compilation error of

error : unreachable statement

As shown in image below:

[image: Compilation error message]

Just remove return false on line 12 as in image above it will compile your program without any error.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean containsAll(IntSet [] s) {


    return false; // <------- remove this 

    // Unreachable Code begins here
    for (int y = 0; y< s.length; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i< s[y].arr.length; i++) {
            if (s[y].contains(i)) {
                if (i>=arr.length) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!arr[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It will obviously not reach the code below the `return` statement. because It will automatically end a method. `return` is use to pass the Object value to the function/method itself. Try to read this too, it will be a lot of help to understand what is the meaning of `return`. -->> [Returning a Value in Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) .